# Why does my code violate the Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

I want to defer non-critical css using the following mechanism:

```
<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

I have the following Content Security Policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; connect-src 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-7cc36362-697e-4b28-bdd9-0400d8923894' 'sha256-1jAmyYXcRq6zFldLe/GCgIDJBiOONdXjTLgEFMDnDSM='; style-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; media-src 'self'; report-uri /api/cspviolation
```

When trying to load and interpret the document, the browser blocks the execution of the onload event handler script because it violates the CSP, which I do not understand because the sha256 of that script is set in the script-src directive.

Any ideas? I've used an online sha256 generator generating the the sha256 set in the CSP. Sadly Chrome does not provide me the sha256 it wants in the console, which I've seen before.

Answer (score 4):

Inline event handlers can only be whitelisted with a hash using 'unsafe-hashes' in CSP level 3, but this is not yet well supported in browsers. Check https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#unsafe-hashes-usage for specification and the table in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy for browser compatibility.

You best option is probably to move the script to a separate file and adding an event listener.

Answer (score -1):

You're using an inline script ("onload=..."), so either your CSP script-src needs to allow `unsafe-inline`, or you need to load the script differently.

Comment: if you disable with `unsafe-inline` the csp check its purpose will be lost !

Comment: Agreed. The better route is to load the script differently!